# Cloudera Manager - dfs.datanode.du.reserved not working

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I have set dfs.datanode.du.reserved property to 10 GB using Cloudera Manager. But when I check the map-reduce job.xml file, I find dfs.datanode.du.reserved is still set to 0. How do I verify whether the property is set ??

PS: I am using Cloudera Standard 4.7.2 with CDH 4.4.0

Comment: Have you distributed the configuration change to your cluster nodes and restarted the Task Tracker? It also might be that you have this value configured in your client configuration (or a default set on the JT's config file set) - in which case it doens't matter as the TT will use it's own configuration value seen at startup, and per job values of this property will be ignored

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I have set this property through Cloudera Manager in all datanodes. And I have distributed the configurations and restarted the map-reduce and hdfs daemons.  But still, the property is not getting set in hadoop configurations..

Answer (score 0):

This flag is set in the hdfs-site.xml and not in the mapred-site.xml.
You will not be able to see this flag in the client configurations (/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml) without tweaking configuration.

It is only set in the datanode configuration that is regenerated by Cloudera Manager. This configuration can be found in /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/XXXXXX-hdfs-DATANODE/hdfs-site.xml, where XXXXXX is a incremented number of some kind (used by Cloudera Manager).

From within Cloudera Manager you can see this flag on Datanode (), click Processes, then Configuration files/Environment - Show and then you find the hdfs-site.xml for a datanode.